# no return statement in friend class

Tags: c++

The warning is being generated by the `ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, A &A0)` function.

## Here's how the class's defined:

```
class A
{
    public:
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, A &A0);
        A& operator=(string strSlot_);
        A& operator+(string strSlot_);
        A& operator+(const A &B);
        A& operator=(const A &B);
        string slotReturn();
        A(string strSlot_);
        A(const A &object);
        void slotChange();
        void sCout();
        ~A();
        A();
    private:
        string strSlot;
        int n;
};


ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, A &A0)
{
    os << "strSlot = \"" << A0.slotReturn() << "\"" << endl;
}

string A::slotReturn()
{
    return strSlot;
}
```

---

The question is, what is it supposed to return? `*this` doesn't seem to work (because it's a `friend`?). (It's merely a warning, but still, I just want to know.)

Also, why can't I pass `A &A0` as a const (in which case the error is: "passing 'const A' as 'this' argument of 'std::string A::slotReturn()' discards qualifiers")?

Comment: Because you need to make `slotReturn()` a const method, as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the `std::ostream&` itself:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream &os, A &A0)
{
   return  os << "strSlot = \"" << A0.slotReturn() << "\"" << endl;
}
```

As an aside, the terminology is slightly off. There is no "friend class". The `std::ostream& operator<<` is the friend here. But it doesn't even need to be a friend, because it just calls a public member function of `A`. So you can remove the friend declaration.

You should probably also make `slotReturn()` a `const` method:

```
string slotReturn() const;
        //            ^ const method
```

and modify the `ostream& operator<<` to take a const reference:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream& os, const A& A0) { .... }
```

This will allow you to print out temporaries:

```
std::cout << A("I am a temporary!") << "\n";
```

Comment: +1 for the extra commentary about terminology and 'does not need to be a friend'.

Comment: @ErgoProxy yes, you will. Friend means "let this function/operator access my private or protected fields", which your operator doesn't do. So the errors must be unrelated.

Comment: @juanchopanza, ah thank you. 
I'll go ahead and clean up the code then; we just started C++ at university, that's why my terminology usage is off. 
Thank you for clarifying that to me. :)

Comment: In addition operator+ has the wrong signature. It should be a const operator and return a copy. It looks like it should be += for which it has the right signature.